# List all commits of a specific year

Tags: git

I need that to generate a report, so I want to list all the commits from the previous year.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+commits+period

Comment: Thanks @phd (even if the duplicate at stake does not mention `rev-list`)

Comment: @ErikMD It mentions `git log` which is perhaps better suited for a report.

Comment: @phd indeed, maybe `git log` would be very fine! it just depends on how the OP will generate the report at stake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could rely on the [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) command?

For example:

```
$ git rev-list --since="1 year ago" HEAD
```

And the `git rev-list` command also contains many options to tweak the ordering, e.g., if you are interested in author timestamps rather than commit timestamps (as I recall that each commit contains *two timestamps*).

By the way I suggest inspecting the command (e.g., passing an extra command-line option such as `git rev-list --pretty --since="…" HEAD` and comparing with `gitk --all` for instance) before relying on the adapted command.

Comment: I am getting: `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: OK, maybe we don't have the same version of the `date` command… but actually the `date` invocation was unneeded! so I simplified my answer accordingly.